# How to bind character vectors with different lengths into a data frame?

Tags: r

I want to bind the outputs from a loop into data frame.

The outputs are like this:

```
> dput(A)
c("u1", "u52", "u190", "u151", "u127", "u131", "u83", "u49", 
"u27", "u186", "u154", "u132")
> dput(B)
c("u2", "u42", "u49", "u132", "u27", "u52", "u48", "u53", "u131", 
"u83", "u54")
```

I hope to bind A and B into a data frame, A and B as two rows. However, A and B have different lengths, I do not want R to recycle values.

Comment: A and B don't have the same number of elements, do you want to add NAs to complete the second row?

Comment: Don't paste printouts of your data, use `dput(A)` and `dput(B)`.

Comment: @fmarm Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rbind() to do this:

```
AB <- rbind(A, B)
```

However, since A and B are not the same length, R starts to recycle. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to recycle, you must add missing values to extend the shorter vector:

```
d <- length(A) - length(B)
if(d > 0) B <- c(B, rep(NA, d))
if(d < 0) A <- c(A, rep(NA, abs(d)))
(AB <- rbind(A, B))
#   [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]  [,8]  [,9]   [,10]  [,11]  [,12] 
# A "u1" "u52" "u190" "u151" "u127" "u131" "u83" "u49" "u27"  "u186" "u154" "u132"
# B "u2" "u42" "u49"  "u132" "u27"  "u52"  "u48" "u53" "u131" "u83"  "u54"  NA
```